# How to create a JavaScript range slider with links?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of numbers like that:

```
<ul class="term-list">
<li class="term-item"><a href="/search?count=1">1</li>
<li class="term-item"><a href="/search?count=2">2</li>
<li class="term-item"><a href="/search?count=3">3</li>
<li class="term-item"><a href="/search?count=4">4</li>
<li class="term-item"><a href="/search?count=5">5</li>
<li class="term-item"><a href="/search?count=6">6</li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is to show this list as a **JavaScript** (range) slider. As you can see, each number has a link.

**What should I do to apply slider to list without losing the link feature?** *I mean if a number selected on the slider (wait 2 seconds), then go to the link with this number.*

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a slidestop event, something like that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').on('slidestop', function(){
        window.location.href = "youpage/count" + $(this).val();
    });
});
```

For the wait two second before changing the page, use `setTimeout(function(){ // code}, 2000);`

Hopes it helps !

- Nic

**P.S.** I assumed you use Jquery-UI.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to `createElement("a");` and you can set Attributes for the generated link

Note: links available from `0` to `100`.

```js
$("#link_generator").on("change", function() {
  //wait 2 seconds
  setTimeout(openURL, 2000);

  //or set attributes

  /* var q = $("#link_generator").val();

  setTimeout(function(){

openURL({
  "href":"/search?count="+q,
  "target":"_blank"
  });

},3000); */

});

function openURL(attr) {
  var q = $("#link_generator").val();

  var a = document.createElement('a');
  if (attr) {
    for (var k in attr) {
      a[k] = attr[k];
    }
    return a.click();
  }
  if (q > 0) a.href = "/search?count=" + q;
  a.click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='link_generator' type='range'>
<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately the setTimeout part of the code doesn't work, it does nothing. Could you please check it? Thanks.

Comment: How? it works for me. the snippet iframe url changes to `so/search?count=5` and displays error `Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.`!! . what do you see? try it locally because snippet iframe has limits with js execution.